# Como identificar regiões de calor em imagens térmicas?

Tags: c, c++, processamento-de-imagens, visão-computacional

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que preciso processar fotos tiradas de uma câmera térmica. A ideia é tentar identificar incêndios nessas imagens. Gostaria de saber quais técnicas posso usar para tal fim, se conhecem alguma matéria, ou algo que possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 22):

Apesar de ter decidido responder essa pergunta, acredito que em perguntas de visão computacional e processamento de imagens, **a pessoa que está perguntando deve mostrar como ela já tentou resolver o problema: listar/descrever as técnicas que aplicou para tentar solucionar o problema, ou mostrar código que faz isso**. Assim a pergunta se torna específica e ela não corre o risco de ser fechada.

**Para evitar um *post* muito longo, esta resposta assume que o leitor possui uma compreensão básica da área de processamento de imagens digitais.**

A imagem abaixo foi adquirida por um dispositivo de imageamento térmico que estava sendo utilizado por [bombeiros durante um treinamento](http://www.firerescue1.com/fire-products/thermal-imaging/videos/397160-Thermal-Imager-Training/).

[image]

O dispositivo de captura possui um sensor que consegue indicar a temperatura aproximada da região central da imagem. A barra verde que aparece no lado direito da imagem acusa que a temperatura da região vermelha está acima de 900 graus. **Desta forma, podemos assumir que regiões com mais calor na imagem terão cores mais fortes.**

O algoritmo que descrevo aqui utiliza o seguinte *pipeline* de processamento:

- Limiarização
- Detecção de contornos

O problema pode ser solucionado aplicando uma operação de [limiarização](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) (*threshold*) para isolar os pixels que possuem um determinado tom de cor, neste caso, vermelho. Esta operação produz a seguinte imagem binária:

[image]

Em seguida, [identificar os contornos dos objetos](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) na imagem binária possibilita localizar as áreas mais quentes. O resultado desta operação é um *array* com os contornos dos objetos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto parece ser exatamente o que você está procurando. Podemos ainda usar esses dados para visualizar na imagem original a área que foi detectada pelo algoritmo:

[image]

Esta abordagem apresenta uma maneira mais simples de resolver o problema. Observe que para obter uma solução mais robusta você deverá testar ela com um conjunto maior de imagens. Esteja preparado para fazer ajustes e aprimorar esta solução.

Existe uma biblioteca de programação que implementa as técnicas que mencionei acima. Estou falando do [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), que é a maior biblioteca open source de visão computacional. Ela é multiplataforma e possui APIs para as linguagens C, C++, Java e Python.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Ah, dá pra usar OpenCV com o Node.js também! :) https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv

Answer (score 10):

O usuário @karlphillip já forneceu uma resposta excelente, mas eu queria complementar com algumas observações e sugestões porém o campo de comentários ficou pequeno. Por isso resolvi adicionar minha própria resposta.

A ideia de utilizar a limiarização faz todo o sentido, principalmente para exemplos como os dados na resposta do Karl. Porém, a pessoa que fez a pergunta (@user6357) não forneceu *sequer uma imagem* do seu domínio de problema, de forma que fica difícil fornecer sugestões realmente concretas. Assim, eu infelizmente concordo com o Karl no fato de que a pergunta está bastante mal feita. Mas independentemente da qualidade da pergunta, eu acho que o conhecimento aqui colocado pode ajudar a comunidade e por isso eu preferi colaborar ao invés de simplesmente sinalizar a questão.

Supondo que as imagens capturadas pela câmera não tenham um fundo (background) tão diferenciado do vermelho como as do exemplo fornecido na resposta citada, a utilização exclusiva da limiarização pode não fornecer resultados satisfatórios.

Dessa forma, eu imagino duas alternativas:

**1. Adicionar à limiarização (ou a qualquer outro método de segmentação) um pré-processamento que considere apenas as áreas da imagem em que há movimento.**

Se você tem controle sobre a captura de imagens da câmera (isso também é algo que você não mencionou na pergunta) e for capaz de tomar duas imagens em sequência, será possível comparar as imagens para verificação das diferenças: uma mera subtração dos valores dos pixels entre as imagens produzirá uma nova imagem cujos pixels serão diferente de zero nas regiões em que ocorre movimento. Na sua pergunta você menciona "incêndios", e o crepitar do fogo naturalmente causa movimento. Se for esse o caso, deve ser possível pré-segmentar a imagem apenas nas áreas em que ocorre movimento para então aplicar o *pipeline* sugerido pelo Karl.

Existem outras soluções com classificadores mais complexos que também utilizam o movimento e também a análise de textura para a detecção de incêndios. [Esse artigo](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi09/cse190-a/reports/ntrue.pdf) é um ótimo exemplo que pode lhe ser útil.

**2. Utilizar um classificador mais complexo.**

Supondo que você não tem sequências de imagens, ou seja, apenas uma única imagem para realizar a detecção e que devido às variações do fundo a utilização da limiarização é insuficiente. Nesse caso, você pode tentar com classificadores mais robustos.

Já que você está usando C++ (e que já foi sugerido o OpenCV, que é uma biblioteca fantástica), eu sugiro utilizar o [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=cascadeclassifier). Você precisará treinar o seu próprio classificador com imagens de exemplo positivas (em que há focos de incêndio) e negativas (em que não há focos de incêndio), e [esse tutorial](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) é muito bacana pra fazer isso (ele detecta bananas nas imagens, mas o princípio é o mesmo - é só usar os exemplos corretos, hehehe).

Esse classificador funciona de uma maneira bastante inteligente: basicamente, durante o treinamento ele "aprende" das imagens de exemplo os valores de intensidade de luz para diferentes tipos de características ([Haar-like Features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features)) que indicam quando há ou não chance de existir o objeto de interesse em uma determinada área da imagem. Como essas características são facilmente escalonadas, é fácil procurar na imagem por variações de tamanho (escala) do mesmo objeto - e na prática é isso que o algoritmo faz: ele busca em janelas de tamanho gradualmente maior até o classificador indicar como verdadeira a ocorrência de um objeto em uma das janelas de busca.

As características que o OpenCV utiliza nas implementações existentes são as da imagem a seguir, que eu creio que elas devem ser suficientes para o seu tipo de problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A descrição no link do próprio site do OpenCV é bem bacana, mas você não precisa entender completamente a ideia desse classificador para utilizá-lo. A qualidade da detecção vai depender apenas da qualidade dos exemplos que você fornecer. No tutorial que eu citei os exemplos de bananas estão todos na horizontal, de forma que o classificador resultante pode não ser muito robusto para imagens com fotos de bananas na vertical. Variações semelhantes podem influenciar no seu resultado, então apenas fique atento à possibilidade de ter de retreinar com mais exemplos.

Comment: Poxa bacana. Obrigado por compartilhar suas ideias conosco! +1

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho experiência no assunto mas sei que [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) é muito utilizada para processamento de imagens, e, se tratando de uma câmera térmica, imagino que áreas mais quentes que o normal sejam destacadas nas imagens com cores apropriadas, menos comuns que o normal, então fazendo um tratamento das cores existentes nas imagens via OpenCV parece uma opção.

Esta é uma referência a respeito usando OpenCV para detecção de fogo e fumaça (neste caso, parece usar cameras comuns mesmo): [FIRE AND SMOKE DETECTION BASED ON LOW COST CAMERA](http://eprints.utar.edu.my/152/1/MH-2011-0702989-1.pdf)